# CustomError throw from server not return in HttpErrorResponse in clientside

Tags: java, spring-boot, angular7, spring-rest

Hi I am pretty new to Spring and Angular.I am building a spring java server and an angular client. Basically , i want the Client to be able to catch the exception throw out from the server. I defined a CustomExeption.java class and have an CustomRestExcepotionHandler.java on serverside. Right now I am not sure where should i throw out the exception in the server for the client to catch.

I was following the tutorial : https://www.baeldung.com/global-error-handler-in-a-spring-rest-api

Now it returns me with 500 Internal Server Error error message to the client side in HttpErrorResponse.

I want it to return my customexception message. Could someone help me to see if server side code has any problem. why did the HttpErrorResponse not catching the CustomException throw out? Thanks!

```
 public class ApiError {

    private HttpStatus status;
    private String message;
    private List<String> errors;

    public ApiError(HttpStatus status, String message, List<String> errors) {
        super();
        this.status = status;
        this.message = message;
        this.errors = errors;
    }

    public ApiError(HttpStatus status, String message, String error) {
        super();
        this.status = status;
        this.message = message;
        errors = Arrays.asList(error);
    }

    public HttpStatus getStatus() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return status;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return message;
    }
}
---
```

--------------------ExceptionHandler

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class CustomRestExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {
    @Override
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleExceptionInternal(Exception ex, Object body, HttpHeaders headers,
            HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {

         ApiError apiError = 
                  new ApiError(status, ex.getMessage(), ex.getMessage());
                return handleExceptionInternal(
                  ex, apiError, headers, apiError.getStatus(), request);
            }

    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleResponseStatusException(ResponseStatusException ex,Object body, HttpHeaders headers,
            HttpStatus status, WebRequest request ){
         ApiError apiError = 
                  new ApiError(status, ex.getMessage(), ex.getMessage());
         return handleExceptionInternal(
                  ex, apiError, headers, apiError.getStatus(), request);
            }

}
```

---

```
public ResponseEntity<AtlasJWT> signInUser(String userName, String password) {String userId = "(uid=" + userName + ")";
if (ldapTemplate.authenticate("", userId, password)) {
                log.info("ldapTemplate.authenticate returned true");

                Optional<AtlasUser> optLoggedInUser = userRepository.findByUsername(userName);
                AtlasJWT atlasJwtToken = jwtTokenProvider.createAtlasJwtToken(optLoggedInUser.get());
                if (optLoggedInUser.isPresent()) {
                    log.info("Atlas JWT: {}", atlasJwtToken);
                    return new ResponseEntity<AtlasJWT>(atlasJwtToken, HttpStatus.OK);
                } else {
                    //ApiError error = new ApiError(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST,"No such User found in the Atlas Database","No such User found in the Atlas Database");
                    throw new CustomException("No such User found in the Atlas Database",HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);
                }

            } else {
                //ApiError error = new ApiError(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN,"Invalid username/password supplied","Invalid username/password supplied");
                throw new CustomException("Invalid username/password supplied", HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);

            }

    }
```

---

my Client side login Component is like below:

```
  login(username: string, password: string) {
    console.log('Inside AuthenticationService. Username: ', username);

    // const body = `username=${encodeURIComponent(username)}&password=${encodeURIComponent(password)}&grant_type=password`;

    const body = {
      'username': username,
      'password': password
    };

    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      })
    };

    console.log('Invoking server authentication for username', username);

    return this.http.post<AtlasJWT>('/auth/api/signin', body, httpOptions).pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
  }

   private handleError(err: HttpErrorResponse) {
    // in a real world app, we may send the server to some remote logging infrastructure
    // instead of just logging it to the console
    let errorMessage = '';
    if (err.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
      // A client-side or network error occurred. Handle it accordingly.
      errorMessage = err.message;
      // console.log(err);
    } else {
      // The backend returned an unsuccessful response code.
      // The response body may contain clues as to what went wrong,
      errorMessage = `Server returned code: ${err.status}, error message is: ${err.message}`;
      console.log(err);
    }
    console.error(errorMessage);
    return throwError(errorMessage);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel like this helped. Added the annotation of @ResponseBody And @ResponseStatus.

[image]

And i also try this code , added in my controller class.both working

```
@ExceptionHandler(CustomException.class)
public HttpEntity<String> exceptionHandler(CustomException custEx ) {
    return new HttpEntity<String>(custEx.getMessage()) ;
}
```